# build boost c++ with mingw

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, mingw

Does I have to specify `cxxflags=-std=c++11` when I build boost c++ library? I am actually using mingw 4.8.0 (x32,posix,dwarf, the same provided by Qt 5.1.0) and boost C++ 1.54.0 (with all patches as specified in the boost download page).

Comment: If you want Boost to make use of available C++11 features, you should do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For building boost itself that was not necessary on my system (gcc 4.8.1, x64). I used on the Windows command promt (not msys):

```
bootstrap mingw

bjam toolset=gcc link=shared variant=debug,release
```

Alternatively you may use b2 [(Reference)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/more/getting_started/windows.html). You have to have boost in your include path, though

```
export CFLAGS="-I/path_to_boost/boost_1_54_0"
export CXXFLAGS="-I/path_to_boost/boost_1_54_0"
```

For compiling programs which should use C++11 features, you need it; independent if boost is used.

Comment: is `bootstrap mingw` equivalent to `bootstrap gcc` on windows?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. But I would guess not.